# How to change position:fixed in other section

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a question,
I have only one section  with set text of the position:fixed . How to set that it is not repeated in other sections ?

thank you for your answer.

Comment: Using an `id`? `<section id="myId"></section>` and `#myId { position: fixed; }`... That will _only_ target that one single instance of a section... I am slightly surprised that you got to CSS `position: fixed` without ever learning about HTML `id`s.

Comment: it is very simple question, you should see css tutorials, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: do you have code example with your issue?

Comment: That is what `id` is for. To target a unique element in html

Answer (score 2):

If it is a one-off case, some will argue that using the style attribute on the `<section>` tag is better, while others will still say that it should remain in the css file. Here are both instances:

## Inline Styling

```
<section style="position: fixed;"></section>
```

## With CSS

```
<section class="fixed"></section>
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: The reason people argue that separate CSS is better is because it means that in the future, you only have to change one file and you can focus debugging on a single file (or type of file if you use multiple stylesheets). And if you want to be semantically correct, an `id` would have been more appropriate for something that has exactly one _single_ instance. :)

Comment: in `no css` example css is in tag)

Comment: @IgorIvancha Good catch, and I think it's very important that the correct wording is used for these simple questions, as it will attract a lot of beginners and they shouldn't get semantically incorrect information on such a simple subject.

Comment: Meh, yeah, semantics.. Since position: fixed is more than a one-off styling, though, I feel as though it would be more appropriate to give it its own class that can be reused, rather than all sorts of random IDs with the same styling rule. It also allows for the section to be rendered dynamically in the future since it does not rely on IDs. Again, it matters so little, I think the OP has much bigger issues to tackle at the current moment ;)

Comment: @IgorIvancha CSS = Cascading Style Sheet. CSS =/= styling. CSS refers to an external file or style tag definition on a page that contains styling rules for html elements. I think the term is misused when referring to all styling. I think technically an inline style is not using CSS. 
http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/CSS-Cascading-Style-Sheet-MIME

Comment: @mhodges I think you are quibbling but it doesn't matter. Change your title to it's correct naming: `inline style`, no? Ow scratch that, you did it now. Thats better!

Comment: I think you do not understand me. I have section with scrollable image on background-attachment:fixed and some one paragraph on position: fixed on every element in this section. 

<section>
 <div class="background-scroll" style="background-image: url(...);"> 
  <p> lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
 <div class="background-scroll" style="background-image: url(...);"> </div>
 <div class="background-scroll" style="background-image: url(...);"></div>
</section>

Comment: Now i'm confused. Since when did background images have to do with your question? Are you wanting the background images fixed, the paragraph text fixed, or every element within a given section fixed?

Comment: I want to have paragraph text on each picture in a fixed position but later text is in the sections stated below

Comment: So you want the paragraph tag in the first section to be position: fixed, but not any of the other paragraph tags in any of the other sections? Or you would like the paragraph tag in all of the sections to have position: fixed?

Comment: I have a lot of section but i want have to paragraph on fixed  only in first section.

Comment: Okay, so your options are as follows. If your sections are in some sort of container, you can use a CSS rule as follows:
#container section:nth-child(1) p { position: fixed; }

If they are not in any sort of container, you can put an ID on the first section element and use a CSS rule as follows: 
#firstSection p { position: fixed; }

Or, you can simply put a style="position:fixed" on the <p> in question or put the fixed class as mentioned in my original answer

Comment: @mhodges 
doesnt  work. paragraph on each section below is on position  fixed

Comment: That doesn't tell me much. Which option did you go with, and how did you implement it? I have a working jsbin here if you would like to see it in action. Without seeing what you are trying, it is hard to determine what the issue is. **Demo** http://jsbin.com/qogahedoti/1/edit?html,output

Comment: That link would have been a good thing to put in your original question.. I am now confused again as to what exactly you are looking for. If you want it to look like the fiddle you linked, take a look at the code and copy what you need. If you don't understand what it's doing and are not willing to put in the time to research how it works and you are here asking for us to write your program for you, we cannot help you.